# How do I alter my gem so that it can run via the command line?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So I am writing a gem that runs through the command line to learn how to count cards.  How do I set the file structure so that the file is run and get get input from the user?

For example what runs the function that makes the code work is a ruby file that contains only the following:

```
require "cardcounter.rb"

CardCounter.run_program
```

Is there a way that when the user downlaods my cardcounting gem, they can just type cardcount and it would run CardCounter.run_program, without having to be in irb or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `bin` directory in your gem's file structure and put the relevant code there (in your case in `cardcount` file).

Read more [here](http://robdodson.me/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/).